# Got error: No rule to make target while compiling linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile my linux Kernel, after customizing my kernel configuration, I taped the command make to start compiling but an error occurs as follows:

```
asma@ubuntu:/usr/src/linux$ make 
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-23/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
```

How can I fix this problem Please

Comment: Where did you get the source from? Are you following the instructions from any wiki/site?...

Comment: Yes i am following instruction from 
[link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=43065) 
but the tuto uses linux-2.6.12 while i am using linux-headers-3.5.0-23 i adjusted the configuration with make menuconfig

Comment: Judging from the instructions in the link, it seems like an issue with permissions. Can you check if compiling using `sudo make` solves the issue?...

Comment: I think it was matter of version, i downloaded a new kernel package and it worked thanks for help

Comment: Nice. :-) Kindly update the steps you took to fix the issue as a new answer to this question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sorry I tried to do as you asked but i think i am not allowed to do so since i still new to the forum, Would you do it please, so that everyone takes benefit.

Answer (score 7):

To build the Linux kernel for Ubuntu,
one can obtain the proper patched sources by running the command,

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
```

(on older versions of Ubuntu, the package name was `linux-tree`)

The sources are installed in `/usr/src/linux-source-<version-num>/`.